# laravel livewire pass data between components

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two livewire components

First i have a foreach loop

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($sectors as $sector)
        <li>{{ $sector->name }} <input type="submit" wire:click="showParent({{ $sector->id }})" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Adicionar"> </li>
        <ul class="mt-2">
        @foreach ($sector->children as $child)
                <li>{{ $child->name }}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This loop display sector and parent sector, them i have a wire:click to pass data to a event listener.
This works fine.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Sector;
use Livewire\Component;

class SectorList extends Component
{
    public $construction;
    public $parent;

    public function mount($construction)
    {
        $this->construction = $construction;

    }

    public function showParent($id){
        $parent = Sector::find($id);
        $this->parent = $parent;
        $this->emit('newParent', $parent->id);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $sectors = Sector::where('construction_id', $this->construction)->WhereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();

        return view('livewire.sector-list', compact('sectors'));
    }
}
```

Second component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Sector;
use Livewire\Component;


class Sectors extends Component
{
    public $sector_name;
    public $parent_id = '';
    public $construction;
    public $segment;

    protected $listeners = ['newParent' => 'submit'];

    public function mount($construction)
    {
        $this->construction = $construction;

    }

    public function submit($id)
    {
        $this->parent_id = $id;
        //dd($this->parent_id = $id);
        
        $data = [
            'name' => $this->sector_name,
            'parent_id' => $this->parent_id = $id,
            'construction_id' => $this->construction,
            //'segment_id' => $this->segment
        ];
        Sector::Create($data);

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.sectors');
    }


}
```

the problem here is that when i submit the parent id gets saved as null, when i double click wire:click="showParent({{ $sector->id }})"  it gets submitted without the name

```````
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">

        <input type="hidden" wire:model="construction" name="construction_id" value="{{ $construction }}">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">{{ trans('cruds.sector.fields.name') }}</label>
            <input  name="sector_name" id="sector_name" class="form-control" wire:model="sector_name">
            <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.sector.fields.name_helper') }}</span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    </form>            
``````
`````
Can someone help??

Thanks
```````

Comment: Are you sure that this line is OK: `'parent_id' => $this->parent_id = $id,` in your second component’s $data array?

Comment: This gets me the id of the parent, i had it like in the first component    $parent_id =Sector::find($id);
      $this->parent_id = $parent->id; but it still the same

Comment: Can you show the markup that shows both of the components together?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the  SectorList component controller, you don't need to pass the variable $sectors as a view parameter, instead place it as public in the class and declare the value inside the render method this way.

```
public function render()
    {
        $this->sectors = Sector::where('construction_id', $this->construction)->WhereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();

        return view('livewire.sector-list');
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, this will make no difference, you can pass variables to views in livewire and sometimes its better to do this.  As the OP has said the issue is with the 2nd Component.